# Disable select value only when value is 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to disable a select option (intervals) when the value of another selection(attempts) is ONLY 1. It stays disabled even if I choose another value from the drop-down.

**HTML**

```
<select id="attempts">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="intervals">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Hello</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
    if ($('#attempts').val() == 1) {
        $('#intervals').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#intervals').attr('disabled', false);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('#attempts').change(function() {
    $('#intervals').prop('disabled', this.value == 1);
}).change(); //auto execute when page load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="attempts">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="intervals">
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>Hello</option>
</select>
```